# EF Core save value from method instead of property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.0

I like to add some data to a column, from a method instead of a property. Is this somehow possible in EF Core?

For example, the config code could look like this:

```cs
internal class MyEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<MyEntity>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MyEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Table1");

        // Add column "Value1" and set it with the return value of myEntity.GetValue()
        builder.Property<string>("Value1").WithValue(myEntity => myEntity.GetValue()); // TODO create WithValue

        builder.HasKey(o => o.Id);
    }
}
```

in this case, the `WithValue` method won't exist.

#### Example:

For example, I will save 2 entities.

1. `GetValue()` for entity 1 returns `"I am Entity 1"`
2. `GetValue()` for entity 2 returns `"I am Entity 2"`

Then I like store `"I am Entity 1"` and `"I am Entity 2"` in the column `Value1`

#### Solution

Jairo's solution with the `ValueGenerator` worked perfect for me! I made the `WithValue` like this:

```cs
internal class ValueRetriever<TEntityEntry, TResult> : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ValueGeneration.ValueGenerator<TResult>
{
    private readonly Func<TEntityEntry, TResult> _retrieve;

    public ValueRetriever(Func<TEntityEntry, TResult> retrieve)
    {
        _retrieve = retrieve;
    }

    public override bool GeneratesTemporaryValues => false;

    public override TResult Next(EntityEntry entry) => _retrieve((TEntityEntry)entry.Entity);
}
```

`WithValue` extension:

```
public static void WithValue<TEntityEntry, TResult>(this PropertyBuilder<TResult> propertyBuilder, Func<TEntityEntry, TResult> retrieve)
{
    propertyBuilder.HasValueGenerator((property, type) => new ValueRetriever<TEntityEntry, TResult>(retrieve));
}
```

Usage:

```
builder
   .Property<string>("Value1")
   .WithValue<MyEntity, string>(myEntity => myEntity.GetValue());
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to solve? Type `MyEntity` will always have same value. Why saving it in to database?

Comment: When saving multiple entities, the values will be different of course

Comment: Okay. I am still not sure what is it you want to achieve. Can you elaborate a bit more.

Comment: There is a way to configure EF Core to use SQL generated values fro properties.

Comment: Or override methods on the DbContext to assing values. That is what I can think of at the moment with info I have.

Comment: Will try to add an example soon.

Comment: Add example, but also the solution thanks to Jairo Alfaro :)

Comment: @dropoutcoder how to use sql generated value for properties?

Comment: @Julian thanks for the solution, does your solution works during update? I couldn't able to save  while updating...

Comment: This only works for adding currently. See also this feature request https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12611

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [shadow properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties) can help you.

EF Core shadow properties let you define & persist non-domain data, data that are not defined in your classes. You define shadow properties in your DbContext, and you use the DbContext to set their values.

To define them:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property<String>("Value1");
```

To set their values:

```
dbContext.Entry(myEntity).Property("Value1").CurrentValue = myEntity.GetValue();
```

Also, you can use the [HasValueGenerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.propertybuilder-1.hasvaluegenerator?view=efcore-3.1) extension method to set a value generator that can get the value from your entity:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property<string>("Value1").HasValueGenerator<ValueGenerator>();
```

The Value Generator:

```
class ValueGenerator : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ValueGeneration.ValueGenerator
{
    public override bool GeneratesTemporaryValues => false;

    protected override object NextValue(EntityEntry entry) => ((MyEntity) entry.Entity).GetValue();
}
```

The entity:

```
class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string GetValue() => $"My Name: {Name}";
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks. Unfortunately I could only change MyEntityTypeConfiguration and not the calling code. Therefore I need something on the EntityTypeBuilder

Comment: Use the HasValueGenerator extension method could be an option, please see my changes.

Comment: Excellent! The `ValueGenerator` approach is exactly where I was looking for :)